# How to have a pytest fixture applied to multiple files

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

What's the recommended way to have `pytest` fixtures applied to multiple test files without setting the fixture scope to `session` (which is too global)?

Here's the structure I'm hoping to use:

```
test_component_1/conftest.py
test_component_1/test_feature_1.py
test_component_1/test_feature_2.py

test_component_2/conftest.py
test_component_2/test_feature_1.py
test_component_2/test_feature_2.py
```

Using `scope='module'` re-applies the fixtures for each file.

I'd like the following behavior instead:

1. set up component_1 fixtures from `test_component_1/conftest.py`
2. run component_1 tests
3. tear down component_1 fixtures
4. set up component_2 fixtures from `test_component_2/conftest.py`
5. run component_2 tests
6. tear down component_2 fixtures

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that is how the scope works. If it is `module` then the fixture would get called per file. In such scenario where the fixture is required in multiple files, I keep its scope as `session`. The only thing is that teardown for component_1 fixture would happen as last step instead of step 3. But that hasn't bothered me so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to expand the scope to more modules (files) without using `scope='session'`. It is anyway good practice to gather all tests for a module in a single file. But if you have very good reasons to do so, you can split it up by renaming

```
test_feature_1.py --> feature_1_tests.py
test_feature_2.py --> feature_2_tests.py
```

and establish `test_component_1.py` which invokes the tests from those files.